# Make a SeekBar look like the ICS style-SeekBar but allow color changing?

Tags: android, styles, themes, drawable, seekbar

I would like to make a SeekBar that looks similar to the default SeekBar in ICS (Holo) but have the ability to change the color in the program.  My app targets ICS but I need it to remain compatible with Froyo and up.

I know I need to set the progress and thumb drawables, and I need to be able to generate these drawables programmatically so that I can change the color.  The thumb shouldn't be too difficult as it is just two concentric circles, the outer one having a lower transparency.

The problem I'm having is the background needs to be a gray line only a few pixels high.  How can I make a Drawable for a thin horizontal gray line that would work as the background of a SeekBar?

EDIT:

I got something very close now using this:

```
private int px_to_dip(int x)
{
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, x, res.getDisplayMetrics());
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void setInterfaceColor(int color)
{
    int dip20 = px_to_dip(20);
    int dip40 = px_to_dip(40);
    Bitmap thumbbm = Bitmap.createBitmap(dip40, dip40, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas thumb = new Canvas(thumbbm);
    Paint  thumbp = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    thumbp.setColor(Color.argb(Color.alpha(color)/2, Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color)));
    thumb.drawCircle(dip20, dip20, dip20, thumbp);
    thumbp.setColor(color);
    thumb.drawCircle(dip20, dip20, px_to_dip(8), thumbp);

    BitmapDrawable thumbdraw = new BitmapDrawable(thumbbm);
    thumbdraw.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, thumbdraw.getIntrinsicWidth(), thumbdraw.getIntrinsicHeight()));
    sb.setThumb(thumbdraw);
    sb.setThumbOffset(0);

    //int colors[] = {Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.GRAY, Color.TRANSPARENT};
    //GradientDrawable prog = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, colors);
    //prog.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);

    Bitmap progbm = Bitmap.createBitmap(sb.getProgressDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth(), dip40, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas prog = new Canvas(progbm);
    Paint progp = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    progp.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    prog.drawLine(dip20, dip20, sb.getProgressDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth()-dip20, dip20, progp);
    BitmapDrawable progdraw = new BitmapDrawable(progbm);


    Rect bounds = sb.getProgressDrawable().getBounds();
    sb.setProgressDrawable(progdraw);
    sb.getProgressDrawable().setBounds(bounds);
    sb.refreshDrawableState();
}
```

The problem is that the background (which should be a 1-pixel-high gray line) goes from the very left to the very right when it should start and end in the center of the thumb.  The thumb is a circle.  I also need to work on sizing a bit.  My px_to_dip mostly works but the size looks a bit off (tested on my 240dpi Galaxy Note (CM9) and my 160dpi Archos A43 (CM7) and HP TouchPad (CM9)).  I'm mainly concerned about the line ending at the right place though, as it's the most annoying thing.